# Display locale language in full

Tags: iphone

I am getting the user preferred language from the below code:

```
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *language = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will return something like 'en' for 'English', or 'de' for 'Deutsch'. Is there any way I can automatically get the full language name, i.e. English instead of en?

Thanks!

Mihai Fonoage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *languages = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
NSString *language = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: This is something very different from what the OP asked for. `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations]` returns the list of languages that your app has been localized into, and has nothing to do with the user's language preferences.

Comment: Apart from that, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations]` only returns language codes as well, so this doesn't help with getting the language display name.

Answer (score 36):

To get a user's list of preferred languages, use `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`. This returns an array of language code strings. To convert those language codes to a display name, you need to use the NSLocale `displayNameForKey:value:` instance method, with the key `NSLocalIdentifier`.

For the display name of the language in your current locale, call that method on `[NSLocale currentLocale]` -- in my case "de" becomes "German". If you'd like the name in the language itself, first create an `NSLocale` instance for that language, then use that object as the receiver. For instance "de" becomes "Deutsch", in German.

This code should make it clear:

```
NSArray *languages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
for (NSString *language in languages) {
  NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:language];
  NSLog(@"language code = %@, display name = %@, in language = %@",
        language,
        [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:language],
        [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:language]);
}
```

And the output on my iPhone:

```
language code = en, display name = English, in language = English
language code = zh-Hans, display name = Chinese (Simplified Han), in language = 中文 (简体中文)
language code = ja, display name = Japanese, in language = 日本語
language code = pt, display name = Portuguese, in language = português
language code = de, display name = German, in language = Deutsch
language code = fr, display name = French, in language = français
language code = nl, display name = Dutch, in language = Nederlands
language code = it, display name = Italian, in language = italiano
language code = es, display name = Spanish, in language = español
language code = pt-PT, display name = Portuguese (Portugal), in language = português (Portugal)
language code = da, display name = Danish, in language = dansk
language code = fi, display name = Finnish, in language = suomi
language code = nb, display name = Norwegian Bokmål, in language = norsk bokmål
language code = sv, display name = Swedish, in language = svenska
language code = ko, display name = Korean, in language = 한국어
language code = zh-Hant, display name = Chinese (Traditional Han), in language = 中文 (繁體中文)
language code = ru, display name = Russian, in language = русский
language code = pl, display name = Polish, in language = polski
language code = tr, display name = Turkish, in language = Türkçe
language code = uk, display name = Ukrainian, in language = українська
language code = ar, display name = Arabic, in language = العربية
language code = hr, display name = Croatian, in language = hrvatski
language code = cs, display name = Czech, in language = čeština
language code = el, display name = Greek, in language = Ελληνικά
language code = he, display name = Hebrew, in language = עברית
language code = ro, display name = Romanian, in language = română
language code = sk, display name = Slovak, in language = slovenský
language code = th, display name = Thai, in language = ไทย
language code = id, display name = Indonesian, in language = Bahasa Indonesia
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe you will need to construct a lookup table for the language codes.  These are [ISO 639-1 codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php).  For more, see the ["Language and Locale Designations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) section of the Internationalization Programming Topics guide.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but apparently there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

For Full Language string like "English" not just "en"

```
NSString * language = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]];


language = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:language]];
NSLog(@"Language=%@",language);
```

Its quite simple for me in language string you will get Full name of your device current language.